# How to make Python Scrapy skip css rules and html attributes

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a spider that crawls for contact details from given url(s).

Works fine, but some of the data its collecting comes from css rules on the pages, for example some `<svg></svg>` attributes may appear as valid numbers. Or some image mappings in `<scripts></script>` like `404_static_desk_1920-w375@1x.jpg` may appear as valid email addresses.

How can I make scrapy ignore certain tags and totally ignore html attributes?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a CSS selector you can add `:not(svg):not(script)` at the end of your selector.

For example if you want to select all element except `svg` and `script`: `*:not(svg):not(script)`

If you edit your question and add an example of how you extract the data I could help you further.

Comment: `sel.xpath("//*[not(self::script or self::img or self::style or self::svg)]")` still returns svg elements inside

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.strip()` method in scrapy as it will remove spaces and characters from the list

```
tag_name = [item.strip() for item in response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"popular_tags")]/*[@class="app_tag"]/text()').extract()]
```

or you can use a library comes with scrapy `w3lib.html`

```
import w3lib.html
output= w3lib.html.remove_tags(yourtexthere)
print(output)
```